# Error in opening Url in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have following code in python 3.5.

```
import urllib.request

prof_list = open(r"C:\local\profanity.txt")
contents = prof_list.read()
connect = urllib.request.urlopen("http://wdyl.com/profanity?q="+contents)
output = connect.read()
connect.close()
prof_list.close()
```

when I run the code, I get

```
 raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Could not figure despite multiple efforts.

Comment: what is the content of profanity.txt ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass one extra argument to `urllib.request.urlopen` like shown in the example below:

```
urllib.request.urlopen('someurl.com', data=None)  # if you have extra data to send to the server
```

Please take a look at this [PAGE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urllib) to know more about the different information to send to a server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the query string before using it in the url.

```
from urllib.parse import quote
encoded_query=quote(query)
```

Then you can use

```
urllib.request.urlopen("http://wdyl.com/profanity?q="+encoded_query)
```